# Extracting text from HTML page in R

Tags: html, xml, r

I am working on drugbank database, please i need help to extract specific text from the below HTML code:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>ATC Codes</th>
    <td>B01AC05
        <ul class="atc-drug-tree">
            <li><a data-no-turbolink="true" href="/atc/B01AC">B01AC — Platelet aggregation inhibitors excl. heparin</a></li>
            <li><a data-no-turbolink="true" href="/atc/B01A">B01A — ANTITHROMBOTIC AGENTS</a></li>
            <li><a data-no-turbolink="true" href="/atc/B01">B01 — ANTITHROMBOTIC AGENTS</a></li>
            <li><a data-no-turbolink="true" href="/atc/B">B — BLOOD AND BLOOD FORMING ORGANS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Text</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

i want to have the following as my output text as list object:

```
B01AC05
B01AC — Platelet aggregation inhibitors excl. heparin
B01A — ANTITHROMBOTIC AGENTS
B01 — ANTITHROMBOTIC AGENTS
B — BLOOD AND BLOOD FORMING ORGANS
```

I have tried the below function but its not working:

```
library(XML)

getATC <- function(id){
    url    <- "http://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/"
    dburl  <- paste(url, id, sep ="")
    tables <- readHTMLTable(dburl, header = F)
    table  <- tables[['atc-drug-tree']]
    table
}

ids  <- c("DB00208", "DB00209")
ref  <- apply(ids, 1, getATC)
```

NB: 
The url can be use to see the actual page i want to parse, the HTML snippet i provided was just and example.

Thanks

Comment: check out the `rvest` package

Answer (score 3):

`rvest` makes web scraping pretty simple. Here's a solution using it.

```
library("rvest")
library("stringr")
your_html <- read_html('<table>
<tr>
          <td>Text</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <th>ATC Codes</th>
          <td>B01AC05
          <ul class="atc-drug-tree">
          <li><a data-no-turbolink="true" href="/atc/B01AC">B01AC — Platelet aggregation inhibitors excl. heparin</a></li>
          <li><a data-no-turbolink="true" href="/atc/B01A">B01A — ANTITHROMBOTIC AGENTS</a></li>
          <li><a data-no-turbolink="true" href="/atc/B01">B01 — ANTITHROMBOTIC AGENTS</a></li>
          <li><a data-no-turbolink="true" href="/atc/B">B — BLOOD AND BLOOD FORMING ORGANS</a></li>
          </ul>
          </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>Text</td>
          </tr>
          </table>')
your_name <- 
  your_html %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath='//th[contains(text(), "ATC Codes")]/following-sibling::td') %>%
  html_text() %>%
  str_extract(".+(?=\n)")
list_elements <- 
  your_html %>%  html_nodes("li") %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_text()
your_list <- list()
your_list[[your_name]] <- list_elements
> your_list
$B01AC05
[1] "B01AC Â— Platelet aggregation inhibitors excl. heparin"
[2] "B01A Â— ANTITHROMBOTIC AGENTS"                         
[3] "B01 Â— ANTITHROMBOTIC AGENTS"                          
[4] "B Â— BLOOD AND BLOOD FORMING ORGANS"
```

Answer (score 2):

Create the URL strings and `sapply` them using the `getDrugs` function which parses the HTML, extracts the root of the HTML tree, finds the `ul` node with the indicated class and returns its parent's text (but only before the first whitespace) followed by the text in each `./li/a` grandchild:

```
library(XML)

getDrugs <- function(...) {
   doc <- htmlTreeParse(..., useInternalNodes = TRUE)
   xpathApply(xmlRoot(doc), "//ul[@class='atc-drug-tree']", function(node) {
     c(sub("\\s.*", "", xmlValue(xmlParent(node))), # get text before 1st whitespace
     xpathSApply(node, "./li/a", xmlValue)) # get text in each ./li/a node
   })
}


ids  <- c("DB00208", "DB00209")
urls <- paste0("http://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/", ids)
L <- sapply(urls, getDrugs)
```

giving the following list (one component per URL and a component within each for each drug found in that URL):

```
> L
$`http://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB00208`
$`http://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB00208`[[1]]
[1] "B01AC05B01AC"                                         
[2] "B01AC — Platelet aggregation inhibitors excl. heparin"
[3] "B01A — ANTITHROMBOTIC AGENTS"                         
[4] "B01 — ANTITHROMBOTIC AGENTS"                          
[5] "B — BLOOD AND BLOOD FORMING ORGANS"                   


$`http://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB00209`
$`http://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB00209`[[1]]
[1] "A03DA06A03DA"                                                           
[2] "A03DA — Synthetic anticholinergic agents in combination with analgesics"
[3] "A03D — ANTISPASMODICS IN COMBINATION WITH ANALGESICS"                   
[4] "A03 — DRUGS FOR FUNCTIONAL GASTROINTESTINAL DISORDERS"                  
[5] "A — ALIMENTARY TRACT AND METABOLISM"                                    

$`http://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB00209`[[2]]
[1] "A03DA06A03DA"                                        
[2] "G04BD — Drugs for urinary frequency and incontinence"
[3] "G04B — UROLOGICALS"                                  
[4] "G04 — UROLOGICALS"                                   
[5] "G — GENITO URINARY SYSTEM AND SEX HORMONES"
```

We could create a 5x3 matrix out of the above like this:

```
simplify2array(do.call(c, L))
```

And here is a test using the input in the question:

```
Lines <- '<table>
<tr>
    <td>Text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>ATC Codes</th>
    <td>B01AC05
        <ul class="atc-drug-tree">
            <li><a data-no-turbolink="true" href="/atc/B01AC">B01AC — Platelet aggregation inhibitors excl. heparin</a></li>
            <li><a data-no-turbolink="true" href="/atc/B01A">B01A — ANTITHROMBOTIC AGENTS</a></li>
            <li><a data-no-turbolink="true" href="/atc/B01">B01 — ANTITHROMBOTIC AGENTS</a></li>
            <li><a data-no-turbolink="true" href="/atc/B">B — BLOOD AND BLOOD FORMING ORGANS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Text</td>
</tr>
</table>'

getDrugs(Lines, asText = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
[1] "B01AC05"                                               
[2] "B01AC Â— Platelet aggregation inhibitors excl. heparin"
[3] "B01A Â— ANTITHROMBOTIC AGENTS"                         
[4] "B01 Â— ANTITHROMBOTIC AGENTS"                          
[5] "B Â— BLOOD AND BLOOD FORMING ORGANS"
```

Answer (score 0):

`readHTMLTable` is not working because it can't read the headers in tables 3 and 4.

```
url <- "http://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB00208"
doc <- htmlParse(readLines(url))
summary(doc)
$nameCounts

      td        a       tr       li       th     span      div        p   strong      img    table ...
     745      399      342      175      159      137       66       49       46       27       27  

#errors
readHTMLTable(doc)
readHTMLTable(doc, which=3)   
# this works
readHTMLTable(doc, which=3, header=FALSE)
```

Also, ATC codes is not within a nearby table tag, so you have to use xpath like the other answers here.

```
xpathSApply(doc, '//ul[@class="atc-drug-tree"]/*', xmlValue)
[1] "B01AC — Platelet aggregation inhibitors excl. heparin" "B01A — ANTITHROMBOTIC AGENTS"                         
[3] "B01 — ANTITHROMBOTIC AGENTS"                           "B — BLOOD AND BLOOD FORMING ORGANS"     

xpathSApply(doc, '//ul[@class="atc-drug-tree"]/../node()[1]', xmlValue)
[1] "B01AC05"
```